# Does HTTP/2 support multiplexing when upload multiple files

Tags: java, file-upload, http2, multiplexing

I know that multiplexing is a feature of HTTP/2 and I've found plenty of examples that show how it works when downloading more resources, but does HTTP/2 support multiplexing when upload multiple files?

Can you share an example (Java is preferred) that shows the performance improvement when uploading with http2 and multiplexing vs standard http upload?

Comment: Multiplexing is useful in situations where you need to make lots of small requests (thus avoiding making lots of connections), not file uploading. There's no performance improvement to be shown.

Comment: @Kayaman, sorry I don't get your point, could please elaborate why not?

Comment: Because normally you need a connection for every resource, so for 100 images you need 100 connections. With multiplexing you can use one connection, so you avoid 100 x time to connect (although it's done parallelly, but still it's cheaper to do it within a single connection than 100 separate connections). So nothing to do with file download or upload or their performance. Useful for small requests only.

Comment: So, if there is a performance improvement in the download there must be even for the upload.

Comment: Well the terminology you're using is a bit confusing. Multiplexing happens for the requests (client to server) and responses (server to client).

Comment: A more comprehensive answer has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60098299/how-to-use-multiplexing-http2-feature-when-uploading/60101100#60101100.